# Android: How do I improve this Image Manager?

Tags: android

I have following code to load images. We load a lot of images on a GridView and we keep on running out of memory. What else can I do to reduce memory usage? Where in the code can I call bitmap recycle?

Thanks.

```
public class ImageManager {
private static ImageManager instance;
    final String TAG = "ImageManager";
    // Cache: memory and file system
    // TODO: HashMap should be replaced with SoftReference or 
    ///      BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private File cacheDir;
    private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache;
    // List of images being downloaded right now. To avoid pulling images twice.
    private ArrayList<String> downloading;


public ImageManager(){
    cacheDir = MyApp.getContext().getCacheDir();
    cache = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
    downloading = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public static ImageManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new ImageManager();
    return instance;
}

public void downloadImage(String url){
    downloadAndDisplay(url, null);
}

public void displayImage(String url, ImageView v){
    downloadAndDisplay(url, v);
}

//-- Private Methods -------------------------------------------------------

private void downloadAndDisplay(final String url, final ImageView v) {
    // Check if image in memory cache. We check disk cache later (it's slow)
    Bitmap cachedBitmap = getFromMemoryCache(url);
    if (cachedBitmap != null){
        AppLog.i(TAG, "Cache Hit (memory), Yay: " + url);
        applyImage(url, cachedBitmap, v);
        return;
    }

    // Set view image to null so a reusable view doesn't show it's
    // old image while we're waiting for the new one to download.
    v.setImageBitmap(null);

    // Check if image is already downloading.
    if (downloading.contains(url)){
        // Already being downloaded. Do nothing.
        // TODO: The view might be different from the one we got before,
        //       we need to consider that possibility.
        return;
    }

    // Download image.
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case HttpConnection.DID_SUCCEED: {
                    AppLog.i(TAG, "Downloaded: " + url);
                    downloading.remove(url);
                    // Apply the image to view (on UI thread)
                    final Bitmap response = (Bitmap) message.obj;
                    applyImage(url, response, v);
                    break;
                }
                case HttpConnection.DID_ERROR: {
                    downloading.remove(url);
                    cacheImage(url, null);
                    //Exception e = (Exception) message.obj;
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
                case HttpConnection.DID_SKIP: {
                    applyImage(url, (Bitmap)message.obj, v);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    HttpRunnable runnable = new HttpRunnable(){
        @Override
        public Object preFetch(HttpConnection httpConnection) {
            // Check if image in cache.
            Bitmap cachedBitmap = getFromCache(url);
            if (cachedBitmap != null){
                AppLog.i(TAG, "Cache Hit, Yay: " + url);
                downloading.remove(url);
                httpConnection.shouldFetch = false; // no need to fetch
                // Cache to memory, we reached this point because it wan't in memory.
                cacheImageToMemory(url, cachedBitmap);
                return cachedBitmap;    
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void postFetch(Bitmap bitmap) {
            cacheImage(url, bitmap);
        }
    };
    downloading.add(url);
    new HttpConnection(handler, runnable).bitmap(url);
}

private void applyImage(String url, Bitmap bitmap, ImageView v){
    // Update view if any.
    if (v != null){
       // Check if the view still intended to display
       // the image we have.
       if (v.getTag().equals(url)){
           AppLog.i(TAG, "--Updating View: " + url);
           v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       }
       else {
           AppLog.i(TAG, "&&& ImageView recycled &&&: " + url);
       }
    }
}

private void cacheImageToMemory(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    cache.put(url, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
}

private void cacheImage(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    // Cache to memory. Even nulls are cached, they indicate an error in 
    // loading the image. This way we don't keep trying to download a 
    // broken image.
    cacheImageToMemory(url, bitmap);

    if (bitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    // todo: consider putting date in file name for easy cleaning 
    //Date date = new Date(0);
    //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    //filename =  sdf.format(date);

    // Cache to disk
    String fileName = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, fileName);
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Ignore. We're creating the file.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Fetches image from memory cache, or returns null.
// Doesn't check disk cache. This function is used because it's fast.
private Bitmap getFromMemoryCache(String url){
    // Check memory cache
    if(cache.containsKey(url))
        return cache.get(url).get();    // might return null if soft reference GCed
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

// Fetches image from memory or file cache, or returns null.
private Bitmap getFromCache(String url){
    // Check memory cache
    Bitmap b = getFromMemoryCache(url);
    if(b != null)
        return b;
    else {
        // Check file.
        String fileName = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        AppLog.i(TAG, "Search file cache for: " + fileName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cacheDir + File.separator + fileName);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you intending to show thumbnails or full images in your `GridView`?

Comment: Instead of cache the image object, how about cache compressed streams?

Answer (score 1):

i recomend you Android Image Manager

http://code.google.com/p/android-image-manager/

it's fast, light, performant, efficient and very easy to use. in most cases all you have to do will be replacing android *ImageView* with *ManagedImageView* in your code or layouts.

it has some soffisticated options, which  allow your application to balance between image quality, memory usage and performance. For example, wise combination will load more than 50MB of images at once and draw them faster than standard *ImageView*

list of all features is on project wiki

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where the decoding of images from the http response is happening, but you might try using [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) from `BitmapFactory.Options` to produce thumbnail images instead of full images.

This should probably happen as you store images into your cache. When you have an activity that needs the full image you could reload it from your file cache in its full glory.

Comment: Matt, 

Thanks for the reply. We are already sending just thumbnail images. We might try resampling it to lower quality and see if it makes a difference.